# How can I update a document in a collection with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a document in my firestore from my React app. To update the value, I'm trying to get the document where the value `uid` is equal to my current user's id. I'm using Firebase V9 and here is my code :

```js
        if(myDescription.length < 15){
            alert("The description must be longer !")
            return
        }
        
        const currentUID = auth.currentUser.uid

        const myDoc = doc(collection(db, "descriptions"), where("uid", "==", currentUID))
        await setDoc(myDoc, {desc: myDescription})
```

But when I execute it I have got this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
    at rt.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1032:1)
    at sa (index.esm2017.js:16044:1)
    at handleClick (Description.js:38:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc(collection(db, "descriptions"), where("uid", "==", currentUID))
```

The `doc` function doesn't expect query conditions like `where`. It's expecting the second argument to be a string, so when it tries to interact with it as a string, it throws an exception.

Instead, you need to use `query`:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "descriptions"), where("uid", "==", currentUID))
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

The snapshot can include an arbitrary number of documents, so you may need to add code to handle what to do if 0 or more than 1 are returned. But you might do something like this:

```
const firstDoc = snapshot.docs[0];
if (firstDoc) {
  await setDoc(firstDoc.ref, {desc: myDescription})
} else {
  console.error("uh oh, it's not there")
}
```